# Gradle Docker Download Dependencies

Tags: docker, gradle, gradle-dependencies

I have a Java Gradle Dockerfile which sets up the Gradle Wrapper, copies the source files, creates a Jarfile and runs it:

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java:9_jdk

WORKDIR /app

# Prepare Gradle
COPY build.gradle .
COPY gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar ./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
COPY gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties ./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
COPY gradlew .
RUN sh -c "./gradlew"

# Download depencencies here?

COPY . .

# Create Jar
RUN sh -c "./gradlew jar"

EXPOSE 7000

# Run Jar
CMD [ \
  "java", \
  "-jar", "./build/libs/projectname.jar" \
  ]
```

This is working fine, but because the jar step is the first stage where dependencies are downloaded, **every time I modify the source code all dependencies need to be downloaded again**. This makes the build cycle quite slower than it needs to be.

I would like to instruct gradle to download dependencies as specified in the `build.gradle` file in a step before copying the source files.

I've tried to simply call `RUN sh -c "./gradlew compileJava"` before copying sources, but gradle is being "smart" and says that there is no work to do, whereas including a single file would actually download the dependencies.

**Is there a way to simply instruct Gradle to download dependencies** as specified in `build.gradle`? Or what would be the best workaround?

EDIT: I am not asking about utilizing the Gradle Cache, I'm asking about leveraging a docker layer to store the gradle dependencies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker cache gradle dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873971/docker-cache-gradle-dependencies)

Comment: You can do it with a custom task like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33542886/750510

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to create a dummy java file and calling `compileJava` download dependencies:

```
# Trick to get Gradle to download dependencies
RUN mkdir -p /app/src/main/java
RUN sh -c "echo 'public class Dummy {}' > /app/src/main/java/Dummy.java && ./gradlew compileJava"
```

To me it seems silly, but at least it works for now.