# Docker: java:openjdk-8-jdk-alpine image missing javac and tools.jar

Tags: java, docker, gradle

I am creating a docker image with following Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:openjdk-8-jdk-alpine

USER root
RUN apk update && apk add docker

COPY . /liveboard-tests
WORKDIR /liveboard-tests
ENTRYPOINT ["./gradlew", ":integration-tests:test", "--tests", "*Foo*"]
```

For some reason the docker container does not contain javac or tools.jar and I cannot compile java code. I have tried various other base images and they all have the same problem.

Can anyone suggest a bullet proof minimal Docker file that will give me a container with ability to use javac and have tools.jar please. TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Gradle you would be on a better position if you use `FROM gradle:X.Y.Z-jdk8-branch` – replace `X.Y.Z` with your project's Gradle version and `branch` with `alpine`, `slim`, etc.; have a look [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/gradle/) for the available tags and/or releases.

And I know this is off topic, again, but using "Docker inside Docker" doesn't work quite well and will give you some surprises down the line.

Comment: Your suggestion worked! I used "FROM gradle:4.6.0-jdk8-alpine" in my Dockerfile. Thank you.

Comment: where is the gradle executable in the container created by this image?

Comment: @FarrukhNajmi, it's in `/opt/gradle/bin/gradle`, but it's `ln`'ed to `/usr/bin/gradle`. You don't need to use the wrapper in this case since it's guaranteed that the version you are working with it's going to be present.

Comment: @FarrukhNajmi remember to run the container with the option `-v gradle-cache:/home/gradle/.gradle` in order to cache the dependencies and avoid downloading them on every compilation as it is stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873971/docker-cache-gradle-dependencies)