# Java Gradle build taking too much time in docker

Tags: docker, gradle, docker-compose, dockerfile, build.gradle

The java build of the project is taking too much time to build in docker environment almost 30 mins with very few dependencies
 This is the dockerfile

```
FROM gradle:4.10.0-jdk8-alpine AS build
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src/producer
WORKDIR /home/gradle/src/producer
RUN gradle bootJar --no-daemon --stacktrace
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/*.jar
COPY --from=build /home/gradle/src/producer/build/libs/*.jar producer.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/producer.jar"]'
```

This is the build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}


group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot-docker-server'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR4")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Please let me know what could be done here? Whenever I run the docker build command, it is trying to pull the dependencies from the network I think so.

```
RUN gradle bootJar --no-daemon --stacktrace
```

But when I try to build bootJar using the Java IntelliJ editor which is the same command which I entered in the dockerfile,  it is taking less than 10 seconds, and even during the first build, it took around 1-2 minutes.

Comment: Are you running in parallel locally? Are you running with a daemon as well? I've enabled both parallel and the daemon in our CI system successfully for the last year and a half. How long does it take locally if you remove the gradle cache completely?

Comment: I guess it is because of gradle's initial download of  everything from stratch. You can check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58593661/slow-gradle-build-in-docker-caching-gradle-build