# Docker build image: reasons for not allowing bind-mounts from command-line?

Tags: docker, gradle, build, mount

Docker build image: what are the reasons for not allowing bind-mounts on command-line? it is a security issue?

Use case:

gradle uses the artifact cache under /home/username/.gradle.

Dockerfile:

```
  WORDIR /opt/app/src
  COPY . $WORKDIR
  gradle build
```

Running gradle inside a Dockerfile will download all artifacts every time building the image.

```
  docker build -t image1 .
```

If bind-mount option is supported, the gradle cache on host can be used, and build will speed up tremendously.

```
  docker build -v /home/username/.gradle:/root/.gradle -t image1 .
```

The option is specified by user on command-line, there should be no security issue.

Comment: Are you asking about [Docker cache gradle dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873971/docker-cache-gradle-dependencies)?  This is an old question with mostly older answers, which discuss "classic" Docker approaches, but a newer answer does mention `RUN --mount=type=cache`.  Disallowing mounts during an image build avoids several confusing cases like hidden dependencies and behavior with remote Docker daemons, and prevents the image build from accidentally modifying the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is better handled with the buildkit `RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/path ...` feature ([documentation available in their git repo](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/52c2fe5ab15da7cdbdff799d96ed85a88761df33/frontend/dockerfile/docs/reference.md#run---mount)).

The resulting Dockerfile looks like:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM base
WORDIR /opt/app/src
COPY . $WORKDIR
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.gradle gradle build
```

The reason to avoid mounting arbitrary folders is that it would add host dependencies into the image build that aren't included in the context (or committed to the git repo). The result is the image may only be able to be built on some machines, or the image might be different depending on where you build it.